# Django: В request не сохраняется аутентификация

Tags: python, django, request

Использую модель профиля унаследованную от AbstractUser

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', u'Мужской'),
        ('F', u'Женский'),
        ('N', u'Не определен'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=1, default='N', verbose_name='Пол')
    father_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=40, verbose_name='Отчество')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='Время последней активности')
    informtation = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='Информация')
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(unpack_ipv4=True, null=True, verbose_name='IP адрес')
```

Аутентифицируюсь

```
def Authentification(request):
    form = forms.RegAndLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ulogin = form.cleaned_data['login']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=ulogin, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return HttpResponse('false')
        else:
            login(request, user)
            user.save()
            current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=ulogin)
            current_user.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            current_user.last_activity = datetime.now()
            current_user.save()
            return HttpResponse('true')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('false')
```

Проверяю

```
def GetServiceVersion(request):
    # request.user всегда AnonymousUser
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        current_user.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        current_user.last_activity = datetime.now()
        current_user.save()
        print('Новые данные сохранены')
    return HttpResponse(settings.SERVICE_VERSION)
```

И получаю, что request.user всегда AnonymousUser, хотя аутентификация проходит

На всякий, url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^version/$', views.GetServiceVersion),
    url(r'^registration/$', views.Registration),
    url(r'^authentication/$', views.Authentication),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Казалось бы, в чем проблема? Всеж верно.
Коллеги, в сотый раз убеждаюсь в том, что решением множества проблем может стать здоровый восьмичасовой сон.
Проблема заключалась в том, что на стороне клиента не отправлялась кука.

Comment: Не могли бы вы поподробней описать процесс решения? В скором времени и у меня будет этот же вопрос :)

Comment: В общем, есть клиент на C#, который общается с сервером на Django посредством POST\GET запросов. В процессе аутентификации на стороне клиента я сохранял куки с сессией, которые мне прислал сервер, но при запросе к _/version/_ , где проверяется, аутентифицирован ли пользователь, клиент сохраненную куку не отправлял, из за чего django всегда возвращал AnonymousUser. На стороне сервера все отлично работает.